# linq predicate with an object

Tags: linq

Previously I used:

```
feeds = feeds.Where(a => a.Address.ToUpper().Contains(ff.Street.ToUpper())).ToList();
```

Now, Address has become a custom object List due to multiple addresses.

```
public class Addresses
{
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    etc
}
```

I'm trying to look inside the object to match any address street names with which ever address is selected from the user. Right now I have:

```
feeds = feeds.Where(a => a.Addresses[0].StreetName.Contains(ff.StreetName)).ToList();
```

This only returns the first one in the List. How do I check it against all street names in the List? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the feed instance again:

```
feeds = feeds.Where(
     aa => aa.Addresses.Any(a => a.StreetName.Contains(ff.StreetName)
).ToList();
```

Or to select matching addresses:

```
addresses = feeds.SelectMany(aa => aa.Addresses)
         .Where(a => a.StreetName.Contains(ff.StreetName)).ToList();
```

Comment: That was it. I had to change the 2nd two a's to b but that was perfect! Thanks!